# data warehouse Initial load from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse, data-migration

We are building a DWH and the initial load would be millions of rows(a few tables have like around 300 million rows). The data will later be updated every 10 minutes using SSIS package which will be like a few thousand rows.Data migration would be from Oracle to SQL Server.

Can you suggest an efficient way of extracting data initially. Is using SQL Server Import and Export a good and faster option than SSIS for initial load?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First: the SQL Server Import and Export wizard creates an SSIS "package under the covers".

I recently had to solve the same problem - our Oracle-to-SQL Server replication infrastructure cratered and we had to rebuild it, which involved initial table loads of the same size that you describe.  We used SSIS packages for all of them, and the performance was sufficient to complete the task in the window we had available.

Another option to consider would be getting the Oracle data as a flat file export and BCP import, if the Oracle data are clean enough.  If you go that route, though, I'm afrad that others will need to assist - I can barely **spell** "BCP".

Comment: hey @Brian I actually tried copying a particular table which had like 18 million rows(for 4 months) and it look approx 4 hours to load it in sql server table from oracle. That table has almost 300 million rows(20 columns) in total and if I use SSIS it will take ages to load. I just wanted a faster way to load the data. And there are a lot of other tables which have similar data size so I was looking for an efficient way of loading data.

Comment: Remember, though that the initial load only has to be done once in an ideal world, and only rarely in the real world.  Also, have you made sure that there's not some other bottleneck in your process?  Network bandwidth, server resources, etc.?  Finally, in what time-frame do you expect to be able to complete the initial load?

Comment: Thanks Brian. I am not sure if there are any other bottle necks & am not sure how to check that.Sorry but I am completely new to DWH. We actually don't have a particular time frame to load data as we are building a DWH internally for the hospital. But there are a few tables with around 300 million rows and as you said "the initial load only has to be done once in an ideal world, and only rarely in the real world" So we are searching for faster options. I had been reading about attunity connector for Oracle which seems pretty fast but I had been having a lot issues installing it for now!!

Answer (score 1):

I just extracted and loaded 24.5 million rows in 9 minutes  from Oracle DB to SQL Server which I found super awesome!!!

Solution : Used Attunity connector for Oracle and change the batch size to whatever suits to you(1000/5000/10000) 1000 worked for me. (default 100)